# Elasticsearch _version field

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

Documentation suggests that `_version` field is per document and is increasing by 1 each time document is updated. After querying data in my ES I see that `_version` field is global for the whole index. (looks like each update is tracked, so my documents have version with value of thousands, which after single update can be increases more than by one, typically some random number, which correlates with global updates in cluster, I guess)

How to change it?

My ES version is **7.14.0**

EDIT1:
I think I need to clarify more:
After `_search` I can see that my documents indeed have like `"_version": 410084,`

maybe it is because I am using kafka-connect with elasticsearch sink to put documents from kafka? Although I don't see any configuration for this sink to manage version by itself

Answer (score 2):

`_version` field is **per document**, I think you are confused with the `seq_no` which denotes the no of updates in a shard and is a counter for the no of updates in a shard, also its not writeable ie Elasticsearch only handles the updates to `seq_no` field.

As `_version` field update can be external, ie you can also updates the value of it, and **if you seeing its getting increase more than one, it means its not being updated by Elasticsearch and someone in your application is updating it, but it doesn't correlates to global updates in cluster in any case.**

Comment: I added edition, can u check?

Comment: @ByeBye, are you updating the document or its just a time series data

Comment: yes, one document is usually updated in average ~30 times

Comment: @ByeBye, ok, so you need to check if you have some setting to provide the external version which is not incremental, refer official blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support for more info... or you can check when a new document is created its version is 1 or something else

Comment: I will check it (new documents are created with big value of version, and it looks like I said, two documents created one by one has n, and n+1 version)

Comment: @ByeBye it seems your application is having a global counter for `_version` which is not correct, it should be per document not per index